# Limiting script access on VPS

Tags: php, apache

Can I get some advice on limiting what PHP can do , for e.g I have a VPS

- home/somesite1.com/
- home/somesite2.com/
- home/somesite3.com/

Let say a wordpress or pyroCMS is install , how can I block code like

```
<?php
$files = scandir('../../../');
?>
```

Where the code could possible delete everything .

Thanks in advance

Comment: su_php to run every site's code under a different ID, chroot jails (pointless if you allow arbitrary code inside the jail), blah blah blah.

Comment: Thanks for the replay - I keep getting the error APXS not install - so mod_suphp wont be installed.